# What is the point in resetting the value of the `trim left` option?

Tags: tikz-pgf

The entry for the `/tikz/trim left` option on pp. 176-177 of the TikZ & PGF manual for version 3.0.1a states (in the end of the option's description, on p. 177):

> Use `trim left = default` to reset the value.

Why would anyone want to reset the value of the `trim left` option? If I understand correctly, (1) this option applies to the entire `\tikzpicture` environment, and (2) like every other option it has local effect.

Fact #1 implies that there is no sense in having more than one `trim left` option in a given environment, and therefore if you find yourself wishing to reset this value, which you had set previously in the current `tikzpicture` environment, you can simply avoid using this option to begin with.

Fact #2 implies that the value of the `trim left` option is automatically reset in every following `\tikzpicture` environment.

So what's the point in writing `trim left = default`? Can anyone please give an example where this feature is put to sensible use?

---

**A `tikz/trim left` usage example**

The `tikz/trim left` option is described in section 15.8 'Establishing a Bounding Box'. The effect of `tikz/trim left=<dimension or coordinate>` is described as follows.

> The effect is the same as if you issue `\hspace{-s}` where `s` is the difference of the picture's bounding box's lower left `x` coordinate and the `x` coordinate specified as `<dimension or coordinate>`.

In other words, the picture is shifted horizontally in such a way that the imaginary vertical line through `coordinate` will pass through the point on the page where the lower-left corner of the bounding box would have normally been located (in the absence of the `tikz/trim left` option).

The following LaTeX manuscript is based on the example given on p. 176 of the manual:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  Text before image.%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[trim left={(0,0)}]
    \draw(-1,-1) grid (3,2);
    \fill (0,0) circle (5pt);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  Text after image.
\end{document}
```

[image: The 'trim left' option in practice.]

Comment: First of all you should give an example of the usage of `trim left`.  I, for example, have no idea what it does.

Comment: @HenriMenke: I've added an example.

Comment: IIRC, picture-wise options can be set globally with `\tikzset{...}`, so you need something that can turn the option back locally.

Comment: @Symbol1: This is a good answer; I've just tried it. Thanks.

Comment: If `every picture` defines a value for `trim left`, `trim left=default` becomes useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example of usage:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={trim left={(0,0)}}}

\begin{document}
  Text before image.%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw(-1,-1) grid (3,2);
    \fill (0,0) circle (5pt);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  Text after image.

  Text before image.%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[trim left=default]
    \draw(-1,-1) grid (3,2);
    \fill (0,0) circle (5pt);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  Text after image.
\end{document}
```